# Javascript failing to see java function

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I'm embedding an applet in a web page and trying to call a function in the applet but get the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'setDestination' when I click the button and the "doit()" function is called. The applet is loaded and on the screen.

Java code (compiled and put into a signed jar named webcam.jar):

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class MyAppletLauncher extends JApplet {

    private JarClassLoader jcl;

   public void setDestination()
    {
       System.out.println("MyAppletLauncher: setdestination!");
       System.out.println(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        jcl = new JarClassLoader();
        try {
            jcl.initApplet("webcam", this);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        jcl.startApplet();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        jcl.stopApplet();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        jcl.destroyApplet();
    }

} // class MyAppletLauncher
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<HTML><BODY>
<applet id=cameraapplet name="camerax" code="MyAppletLauncher.class" height="100%" width="100%" archive="webcam.jar">
</applet>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function doit() {
alert(1);
document.camerax.setDestination(); // Dies on this line
alert(2);
}
</Script>
<input type=button onclick='doit();'>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this compiles given that `url` isn't declared anywhere before it's used.  Or is this not the complete class?

Comment: If no http:// then it is assumed to be current directory on the webserver, so the applet is being loaded from webcam.jar in the same directory the html is in.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you might want to look into `deployJava`, a library from Oracle for deploying applets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html - it helps with browser inconsistencies

Answer (score 0):

Use the applet id to get a reference to the applet object:

```
document.getElementById("cameraapplet").setDestination();
```

Note however that the `<applet>` tag is not supported by HTML5. [Read this article](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/63-How-to-use-Java-applets-in-modern-browsers.html) on how to use 
`<embed>` or `<object>` for Java applets.

Comment: The html code is identical to code I use with a scanner applet and works fine. I did do this though, just to be sure and it gave me the same message. It appears the functions in the Java code are not visible to the outside world, but I thought that's what "public" did. I'm open to other thoughts though :).

Yeah, I know I'll need to recode for html5, but that's going to be a rewrite of lots of code on a legacy system.

Comment: @bkeahl Is your JAR signed? Does it have the correct manifest entries to allow communication **from** JS?

Comment: For that matter, what is JarClassLoader?  It's not part of the standard Java SDK... or at least it isn't in JDK7.

Comment: Ian, the jar is signed with a Comodo certificate and I'm getting no security warnings. Here's the relevant manifest entries:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Created-By: 1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation)
Codebase: *

Comment: I know you say there's no security warnings, but here's the relevant manifest entries I use: `Application-Name: AppName | Permissions: all-permissions | Codebase: * | Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *`. I need the `Permissions` one because I access secure things, personally. Maybe try those too and see if that changes anything. I recently had the same troubles as you, and found it was a manifest entry I needed (just not sure which one)

Comment: I made sure I had all those elements and signed the jar.  No joy.  The console shows the debug output I added as well.  It's just that javascript can't see the java functions.

Comment: After tinkering a bit I can communicate from javascript to the code above (call a function). But what I really need to do now is call a function in webcam applet I'm loading here.  Is there a way for this code to communicate with the applet it is loading or for javascript to communicate directly with the loaded applet?